# How to change live agent offline message?

Tags: liveagent

If live agent is not online and the chat session is initiated the customers will see [image]

Can we change the text of this message as well as the hyperlink in close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom chat window and configure your message using the component **liveAgent:clientChatMessage**s

See the section "Live Agent Visualforce Components" in the [Live Agent Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index.htm)